# Installing and compiling cplexAPI package source for R

Tags: r, api, installation, package, cplex

OS: Windows 7 x64

R Installation: 2.15.1 x64

Cplex instalation: Cplex Studio Academic 124 (both 32 and 64bit)

I installed Rtools and I have an independent cygwin installation with all the required packages. I also have MikTex Installed...

I have the following evironment flags set...

```
CPLEX_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124
CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR=C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124
CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB32=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\bin\x86_win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\bin\x86_win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cpoptimizer\bin\x86_win32
CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB64=C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64
```

Then when I run the install command in R I get the following errors

---

```
> install.packages("c:/cplexAPI_1.2.2.tar.gz", type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/root/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\include"         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\include"         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplexR.c -o cplexR.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\include"         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_checkAPI.c -o cplex_checkAPI.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\include"         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c cplex_longparamAPI.c -o cplex_longparamAPI.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\include"         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o cplexAPI.dll tmp.def cplexAPI.o cplexR.o cplex_checkAPI.o cplex_longparamAPI.o init.o -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124 -LC:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Academic124\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64 -lm -lcplex124 -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcplex124
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/root/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/cplexAPI'
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Users/root/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "c:/cplexAPI_1.2.2.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("c:/cplexAPI_1.2.2.tar.gz", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘c:/cplexAPI_1.2.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing

Comment: You have spaces in the path to cplex124.

Comment: Does it actually matter? is the gcc compiler which comes with Rtools actually incapable of handling paths which go to "Program Files"? Seems unreasonable since everything installs in there on a windows machine...

Comment: Windows is often unreasonable.  Yes, it matters.  Paths with spaces in them must often be quoted.

Comment: @Constantine:  I encounter a similar error. Did quoting all paths solve the problem? Could you come up with a solution?

Comment: No, I never managed to get it to work. Instead, I contacted the package developer and he sent me the compiled binaries. However, I have long since ceased using this particular combination of platforms due to the hassle and computational overhead.